# Creating xml files from a database or list of variables

Tags: xml, text, text-files

I have a template and need to create several xml files. The file contains one variable -this- to replace several times, save it as that name -this-.xml and then repeat for each of the values in my text or excel list or from a database  - How would I best go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Old school unix way (bash shell syntax):

```
for var in $(cat replacelist.txt); do sed "s/-this-/$var/g" < template.xml >$var.xml; done
```

Comment: You risk producing not-wellformed XML. At the very least, you should escape $var before!

Comment: Well, it's a fairly well constrained case: we're not talking something coming from a random user input web form: this is old-school automation of an individual's work: if it breaks, you can keep both pieces.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking at doing this in code, or using a template-driven generator?

Several choices:

- inside Visual Studio, you could use a T4 template to achieve this
- you could use a code generator such as CodeSmith, MyGeneration or others
- you could write your own little program to do this (in C#, VB - anything)

Which of these are you really looking for?

Marc

Comment: I am just looking for the simplest way - there's know way that I would be able to write a program to do this - I got the idea form using BK Replaceem and thought I may be able to use a list to kind of do the opposite of that program - Thanks

Comment: Well, in that case, I would say have a good look at MyGeneration - it's a template-driven code/textfile generator - you should have no trouble creating your template and then filling in the blanks from a CSV or XML file or something. Go to http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/